# 「匿名で質問した後でコメントや回答の承認ができない」場面にどう対応すべき？

Tags: 討議

匿名の質問に対して「解決できました」といった編集の提案や、回答を見かけることがあります。

例 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3837

おそらく[クッキーを削除したなどの理由で](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44562)質問者として認識されず、コメントや承認ができないのだろうと思います。

こういう場面に遭遇したらどのように対応するとよいでしょうか？

- アカウントのマージを薦める（匿名のまま使いたい人には難しいかもしれませんが）
- モデレータに通報する
- その他

Answer (score 2, accepted):

推奨編集された投稿に「通報」してください。

「その他」の選択で状況を説明すれば、マージ等の適切な行動します。

（できれば、両方のアカウントのリンクを提供すれば、解決がやりやすくなりますが、時間がなかったら通報と簡単な説明をすれば大丈夫です）